# I lost my way home on Minecraft. How do I find it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was in Minecraft creative mode and built a whole city. Then I decided to explore the world for a bit in survival mode. After a while, I died but it didn't take me back home. It said my bed was not found or obstructed. Please help me, I worked so hard with that world. I don't remember the coordinates.